# Tooltip on v-for repeating element in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a repeating avatar in a v-for block in vuetify, and would like to add a tooltip around each one with their respective names. This is what I have so far, but it does not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<span v-for="(zone, i) in getZoneArray(item)" :key="i">
  <v-tooltip top>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-avatar
        :color="zone.detail.hex_color"
        size="30"
        class="text-uppercase white--text"
        >{{ zone.display_name.charAt(0) }}
      </v-avatar>
    </template>
    <span>{{ zone.display_name }}</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your codes, the simplest solution is add `v-on="on"` into the `button/v-avatar` inside the slot.

Another solution is uses `v-model` to control if show the tooltip.

Below is **one demo** for above two solutions:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    getZoneArray: function () {
      return [
        {
          detail: {hex_color: 'red'},
          display_name: 'a-test'
        },
        {
          detail: {hex_color: 'blue'},
          display_name: 'b-test'
        }
      ]
    },
    getZoneArray2: function () {
      return [
        {
          detail: {hex_color: 'red'},
          display_name: 'a-test',
          show: false
        },
        {
          detail: {hex_color: 'blue'},
          display_name: 'b-test',
          show: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<v-app id="app">
  <h4>Solution 1:</h4>
  <span v-for="(zone, i) in getZoneArray()" :key="i">
    <v-tooltip top>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-avatar
          :color="zone.detail.hex_color"
          size="30"
          class="text-uppercase white--text"
          v-on="on"
          >{{ zone.display_name.charAt(0) }}
        </v-avatar>
      </template>
      <span>{{ zone.display_name }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </span>
  <h4>Solution 2:</h4>
  <span v-for="(zone, i) in getZoneArray2()" :key="i">
    <v-tooltip top v-model="zone.show">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-avatar
          :color="zone.detail.hex_color"
          size="30"
          class="text-uppercase white--text"
          >{{ zone.display_name.charAt(0) }}
        </v-avatar>
      </template>
      <span>{{ zone.display_name }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </span>
</v-app>
```